# How to redirect in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am having issue redirecting users to a new page when they are successfully authenticated, I am using auth0 and a token is being returned when the user is successfully authenticated, I need a way to redirect users to the dashboard page after saving the token in AsyncStorage. Below is what I have been able to come up with.

```
export function login(credentials) {
  saveItem('token', credentials.idToken)
}

export async function saveItem(item, selectedValue) {
  try {
     await AsyncStorage.setItem(item, selectedValue);
  } catch (error) {
     console.error('AsyncStorage error: ' + error.message);
  }
}
```

Comment: You havent mentioned whether you are using any routing library.

Comment: I am using react-navigation